# How can I create agent populations within an agent population

Tags: anylogic

I am having this issue with Anylogic, hope to get some help :)

The situation is the following: I have a population of agents X  that has 10 different agents inside it, I need to pick up these different agents and put them in the "container agent" which is my pallet, and finally store them in the Pallet Rack.

The agents are different products being produced in the same location. There is a database stating each product when will it be produced and the amount of it.

I have created the agent X, how can I create 10 different agents within it?

Comment: Welcome to SOF. Please split this into separate questions, 1 for each issue. Also, be more specific which each question, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have an agent population within an agent population, do this:

1. Have an agent type "Containers"
2. drag that into Main to create a population "pop_Containers". Load it as you like
3. Create another agent type "Products"
4. Open the "Containers" agent type and drag in "Products" to create a "pop_Products" within "Containers"
5. Load your products for each container as you see fit. This depends on your specifics of your database structure.